# Automated Road Link

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road

I have a polyline shapefile of roads of a municipality. Each road has a unique ID (for example AR1002, AR1003 etc.) Now I want to add a field in the shapefile which will contain the ID of each road that intersect a particular road. For example, Road AR1000 is connected to Road AR1003, AR1010, and AR0999. Now In a different field, how could I have these three IDs with respect to AR1000?

Comment: In general, you should avoid having multiple values in a single field, which is what you would get when a road intersects more than one other road.  What is the purpose of recording these ID values?  Perhaps there is a better way of achieving that purpose.

Comment: If you have an advanced license you could perform feature vertices to points with BOTH_ENDS https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000 then generate near table https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000 with a small search distance and closest = 'ALL', remove the features from the table that find themselves then all you need to do is digest the table - therein lies the *real* work. Do you have an advanced license? Are you doing this in model builder or python? you won't find a combination of interactive tools to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A classical case of [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm). Select your road network as both target and join features. And then set the Join Operation to **one to many** and pick Intersects as Match Option. This will create as many records as the number of intersecting road segments to each row.

If you want to see all connected feature in a field as one row/line, which is not a good practice as explained in the comments, you can pick one to one option and create a new text field where you will "join" all intersecting features with a delimiter by [setting the merge rules](https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/). Only critical issue here is to select right size for your new text field, it should be long enough to have all features in a delimited fashion.

Alternatively you can use [Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) tool, which will give a similar result to the first option where then you can join your features to get the IDs/Names.